# What is _Tidy_deallocate_guard in C++ used for?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, struct, stl

What is the use of _Tidy_deallocate_guard? It is present inside xmemory internal header of C++. Why it calls _Tidy_deallocate?
Can you please explain.

```
// STRUCT TEMPLATE _Tidy_deallocate_guard
template <class _Ty>
struct _Tidy_deallocate_guard { // class with destructor that calls _Tidy_deallocate
    _Ty* _Target;
    ~_Tidy_deallocate_guard() {
        if (_Target) {
            _Target->_Tidy_deallocate();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: That's an internal header of *one* implementation of the C++ Standard Library, so it is of no general interest. If you are just curious to follow what it does, look at one of the places where it's used, for example [`xstring`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/xstring). Basically, it ensures that any exception thrown in the "*guarded*" code causes a particular member function (`_Tidy_deallocate`) to be called before leaving the scope.

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Tidy_deallocate_guard`, `_Ty`, `_Target`, `_Tidy_deallocate`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. You're digging into internal implementation details.